# calculate CFM of a ceiling fan

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, air, cooling, fan

I'm trying to calculate, or even understand what data do i need to calculate the CFM of a ceiling fan. in many countries this is a given data in the product details but not where I'm from. I have the following info 
speed=190 cycles/min, blades diameter =  52 inch, power = 35W, room size ~215 cf, num of blades = 3 , distance from ceiling (lets say a constant variable), and the shape they have is rather complicated to describe - starts in the middle of the blade (circle center) as vertical to the floor and by the the end , the blade is parallel to the floor (photo attached). can you suggest how to calculate the cfm, maybe by neglecting some of the  less important parameters..?[image]